# Huawei push sdk for Android target 31

Tags: android, push-notification, push, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

current version sdk push for Android crashes in 31 target sdk. Need to mark exported manifest dependencies to bump New build rules.
When will New version with support target sdk be released?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Just confirmed with the team, pls upgrade the push kit version to **6.1.0.300** will solve your problem.

```
    // push kit
    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:6.1.0.300'
```

---

Thanks for your feedback, the  R&D team confirms that push kit for android 12 is planned in mid-to-late September. Please use the latest version for testing by that time. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, can i use dev or test version for this? Can you have repository link?

Comment: hi@Denis A, i just updated my answer, pls kindly refer that.